# How can I set the Transformation-Matrix in Libharu?

Tags: pdf, scaling, libharu

I want to use libharu to render my documents to PDF.
I would like to set a global scalefactor, which translates my document coordinates to the pdf-page coordinates.

The only function in libharu, which has to do with scaling, is `HPDF_Page_GetTransMatrix(page)`.

`HPDF_Page_GetTransMatrix()` returns the struct `HPDF_TransMatrix` as a value, not as a reference, so I cannot change the scaling by setting the elements of that returned matrix.

I miss the Set-Counterpart for the function `HPDF_Page_GetTransMatrix()`-function.

How can I set a scalefactor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HPDF_Page_Concat()` is the function I looked for. See 
[here](http://libharu.org/wiki/Documentation/API/Graphics#HPDF_Page_Concat.28.29)